# Installing Hadoop, Java Exception about illegal characters at index 7?

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, installation

Following this tutorial for all the configurations: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Get this error, can get my task tracker and job tracker up, but others keep giving me this error:

```
013-07-03 19:39:44,918 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = slaveone-12499.phx-os1.stratus.dev.ebay.com/10.9.247.151
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.2.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2 -r 1479473; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Mon May  6 06:59:37 UTC 2013
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_25
************************************************************/
2013-07-03 19:39:45,143 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-07-03 19:39:45,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-07-03 19:39:45,159 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-07-03 19:39:45,160 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2013-07-03 19:39:46,682 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-07-03 19:39:46,729 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-07-03 19:39:46,806 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: hdfs://localhost:54310
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getDefaultUri(FileSystem.java:131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(FileSystem.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1683)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1798)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: hdfs://localhost:54310
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3167)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3078)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
        ... 8 more

2013-07-03 19:39:46,820 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at slaveone-12499.phx-os1.stratus.dev.ebay.com/10.9.247.151
************************************************************/
```

Not sure what's wrong, I've tried to find an illegal character but have been failing to find one? I also looked at the previous stack overflow question about this, but not sure how it was supposed to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a spacing issue in the XML, in between the opening and closing  and  tags. Double check those!